# Apache POI, throwing UnsupportedZipFeatureException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for reading xsl files. My pom file update:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code:

```
  public List<String> getSheetNames(String fileLocation) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //do something with read lines
  }
```

This works fine for some files. However, for others it throws this error:

org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnsupportedZipFeatureException: Unsupported feature compression method used in entry ...
...
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipUtil.checkRequestedFeatures(ZipUtil.java:353)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.read(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:514)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.read(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:80)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:185)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:153)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:140)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveFakeEntry.(ZipArchiveFakeEntry.java:72)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:98)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:132)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:312)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:59)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:304)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:300)

what's the fix for this error? I haven't been able to find much help online.

UPDATE: This is not working for any file now.

Comment: There is no "fix for this error" as it is probably caused by a corrupted file behind your `fileLocation`. Excel itself may be tolerant enough to ignore this corruption but Apache POI (respective Apache Commons Compress) is not. So file a bug in https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?list_id=202094&product=POI but add the Excel file causing this error as attachment there. Without having that file it will be nearly impossible to detect what problem causes this error.

Comment: Ok I debugged the issue. It isn't related to Apache poi at all, it was due to another piece of code where I was reading the file and rewriting it, before passing it to this method. In the process, the file probably gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Make the changes like this. if the file is of type xls, you have to use HSSFWorkbook obj to read it

```
public List<String> getSheetNames(String fileLocation) throws Exception{
    File inputFile = new File(fileLocation);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    Workbook workbook = null;
            
    try {
        if (inputFile.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        } else if (inputFile.getName().endsWith(".xls")) {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        } else{
            fis.close();
            throw new IOException("This file extension type is not supported!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //do something with read lines
}
```

Comment: Make sure to close the fis, once you're done using it

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. However, my file is .xlsx and I am using the same code.

Comment: Apache POI has `WorkbookFactory` that does an even smarter version of this to detect the right type for you